# Why new Decimal and Decimal works differently?

Tags: vb.net, scope

```
        For a = 1 To 100
            Dim e As Decimal
            Dim g As New Decimal
            If e <> 0 Then
                Dim f = 1 'breakpoint here
            End If
            e += 1
            g += 1
        Next
```

I wrote this simple program.

I thought the scope of e is simply inside For Next

So every time For Next is called, we have a new e variables.

But not.

Value of e keeps increasing.

Value of g resetted.

Why?

I wonder if Decimal is an object or a primitive type.

It doesn't seem to matter

```
        For a = 1 To 100
            Dim h As Double
            Dim i As New Double
            Dim e As Decimal
            Dim g As New Decimal
            If e <> 0 Then
                Dim f = 1 'breakpoint here
            End If
            e += 1
            g += 1
            h += 1
            i += 1
        Next
```

The value of h is also increasing

Comment: [Block Scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/scope#block-scope). Read the **Note**  box.

Comment: [^^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75509349/why-new-decimal-and-decimal-works-differently?noredirect=1#comment133224312_75509349) and `New` creates a new value, nothing to do with the scope or loop: https://dotnetfiddle.net/q6LCHl

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think in this case, it's more accurate to say that `New` forces calling the constructor of the type.  In the case of a primitive numeric type, that resets the value to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VB.NET (and only in VB.NET), an uninitialized variable within a loop is auto-initialized by VB once and only once. The "as new" case is just shorthand for an initialization using 'new', so there is no auto initialization happening there.

In addition, as dr.null pointed out, the documentation states that "If you enter the block more than once during the procedure, each block variable retains its previous value" - [Scope in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/scope#block-scope). Even though the scope is the loop, the 'lifetime' is the entire method.

In VB, it's good practice to initialize local variables, especially within loops.

Comment: So it's different than C# or C++.

Comment: @obfuscated: Yes - also different than Java and Python (there are hundreds of VB features which are unique to VB).